# How to test a styled-component to have a property with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I have a styled-component wrapping an input checkbox element with some styling. In my app, this checkbox could be already checked by default. This is some of the component code:

```
const InputCheckbox = styled.input.attrs((props) => ({
    id: props.id,
    type: 'checkbox',
    checked: props.checked
}))`
    visibility: hidden;

    &:checked + label {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.mainColor};
        border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.mainColor};

        &:after {
            border-left: 2px solid #fff;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
        }
    }
`;


function Checkbox(props) {
    return (
        <CheckboxContainer>
            <InputCheckbox
                id={props.id}
                checked={props.checked}
                onChange={(event) => {
                    props.onChange(event.target.checked);
                }}
            />
            <CheckboxLabel id={props.id} />
        </CheckboxContainer>
    );
}
```

I'm using Jest and Enzyme for testing but I couldn't find any information on how dive into your Enzyme shallow wrapper to check that the input inside my InputCheckbox has the checked property as true. For example:

```
describe('Checkbox', () => {
    const mockProps = {
        id: 'settings-user',
        checked: true,
        onComplete: (id) => jest.fn(id)
    };

    const component = shallow(<Checkbox {...mockProps}/>);

    describe('on initialization', () => {
        it('Input should be checked', () => {
            const inputCheckbox = component.find('InputCheckbox');
            expect(inputCheckbox.props().checked).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

This test fails because the `.find()` can't find any node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need set display name for use find by it:

   `InputCheckbox.displayName = 'InputCheckbox';`


   After that try
   `component.find('InputCheckbox')`

   For more convenience use [babel plugin](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging).
2. Also try use find with component constructor.

   ```
   import InputCheckbox from 'path-to-component';

   ...

   const inputCheckbox = component.find(InputCheckbox);
   ```
3. Perhaps for access child component in you case need use 'mount'
   insted of 'shallow'.

Comment: Thank you this works exactly as I expected. To avoid using `mount` I'm just checking that the styled component has the prop.